# Product saving problem in admin control panel

Tags: magento-2.2.1

I have already uploaded the product details in to magento, but whenever i try to make any small change (example: quantity) it does not work and it gives me this error:

Unable to save Stock Item

I have already tried several times and i always get this error message. Can you guys help me with this issue.

[image]

**VAR/SYSTEM.LOG ERROR DETAILS:**

```
[2018-02-21 04:36:22] main.CRITICAL: Exception message: Unable to save Stock Item
Trace: #0 /home/tesefa/public_html/vendor/magento/module-catalog-inventory/Model/StockRegistry.php(180): Magento\CatalogInventory\Model\Stock\StockItemRepository->save(Object(Magento\CatalogInventory\Model\Adminhtml\Stock\Item))
#1 /home/tesefa/public_html/vendor/magento/module-catalog-inventory/Observer/SaveInventoryDataObserver.php(110): Magento\CatalogInventory\Model\StockRegistry->updateStockItemBySku('Tevere-7353-992', Object(Magento\CatalogInventory\Model\Adminhtml\Stock\Item))
#2 /home/tesefa/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Event/Invoker/InvokerDefault.php(72): Magento\CatalogInventory\Observer\SaveInventoryDataObserver->execute(Object(Magento\Framework\Event\Observer))
#3 /home/tesefa/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Event/Invoker/InvokerDefault.php(60): Magento\Framework\Event\Invoker\InvokerDefault->_callObserverMethod(Object(Magento\CatalogInventory\Observer\SaveInventoryDataObserver), Object(Magento\Framework\Event\Observer))
#4 /home/tesefa/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Event/Manager.php(66): Magento\Framework\Event\Invoker\InvokerDefault->dispatch(Array, Object(Magento\Framework\Event\Observer))
#5 /home/tesefa/public_html/generated/code/Magento/Framework/Event/Manager/Proxy.php(95): Magento\Framework\Event\Manager->dispatch('catalog_product...', Array)
#6 /home/tesefa/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Model/AbstractModel.php(818): Magento\Framework\Event\Manager\Proxy->dispatch('catalog_product...', Array)
#7 /home/tesefa/public_html/vendor/magento/module-catalog/Model/Product.php(928): Magento\Framework\Model\AbstractModel->afterSave()
#8 /home/tesefa/public_html/generated/code/Magento/Catalog/Model/Product/Interceptor.php(362): Magento\Catalog\Model\Product->afterSave()
#9 /home/tesefa/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/EntityManager/Observer/AfterEntitySave.php(34): Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Interceptor->afterSave()
#10 /home/tesefa/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Event/Invoker/InvokerDefault.php(72): Magento\Framework\EntityManager\Observer\AfterEntitySave->execute(Object(Magento\Framework\Event\Observer))
#11 /home/tesefa/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Event/Invoker/InvokerDefault.php(60): Magento\Framework\Event\Invoker\InvokerDefault->_callObserverMethod(Object(Magento\Framework\EntityManager\Observer\AfterEntitySave), Object(Magento\Framework\Event\Observer))
#12 /home/tesefa/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Event/Manager.php(66): Magento\Framework\Event\Invoker\InvokerDefault->dispatch(Array, Object(Magento\Framework\Event\Observer))
#13 /home/tesefa/public_html/generated/code/Magento/Framework/Event/Manager/Proxy.php(95): Magento\Framework\Event\Manager->dispatch('magento_catalog...', Array)
#14 /home/tesefa/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/EntityManager/EventManager.php(52): Magento\Framework\Event\Manager\Proxy->dispatch('magento_catalog...', Array)
#15 /home/tesefa/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/EntityManager/Operation/Update.php(110): Magento\Framework\EntityManager\EventManager->dispatchEntityEvent('Magento\\Catalog...', 'save_after', Array)
#16 /home/tesefa/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/EntityManager/EntityManager.php(96): Magento\Framework\EntityManager\Operation\Update->execute(Object(Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Interceptor), Array)
#17 /home/tesefa/public_html/vendor/magento/module-catalog/Model/ResourceModel/Product.php(626): Magento\Framework\EntityManager\EntityManager->save(Object(Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Interceptor))
#18 /home/tesefa/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(58): Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product->save(Object(Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Interceptor))
#19 /home/tesefa/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138): Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Interceptor->___callParent('save', Array)
#20 /home/tesefa/public_html/vendor/magento/module-catalog-search/Model/Indexer/Fulltext/Plugin/Product.php(51): Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Interceptor))
#21 /home/tesefa/public_html/vendor/magento/module-catalog-search/Model/Indexer/Fulltext/Plugin/Product.php(24): Magento\CatalogSearch\Model\Indexer\Fulltext\Plugin\Product->addCommitCallback(Object(Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Interceptor))
#22 /home/tesefa/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(135): Magento\CatalogSearch\Model\Indexer\Fulltext\Plugin\Product->aroundSave(Object(Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Interceptor))
#23 /home/tesefa/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/App/Cache/FlushCacheByTags.php(68): Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Interceptor))
#24 /home/tesefa/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(135): Magento\Framework\App\Cache\FlushCacheByTags->aroundSave(Object(Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Interceptor))
#25 /home/tesefa/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(153): Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Interceptor))
#26 /home/tesefa/public_html/generated/code/Magento/Catalog/Model/ResourceModel/Product/Interceptor.php(273): Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Interceptor->___callPlugins('save', Array, Array)
#27 /home/tesefa/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Model/AbstractModel.php(647): Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Interceptor->save(Object(Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Interceptor))
#28 /home/tesefa/public_html/generated/code/Magento/Catalog/Model/Product/Interceptor.php(2429): Magento\Framework\Model\AbstractModel->save()
#29 /home/tesefa/public_html/vendor/magento/module-catalog/Controller/Adminhtml/Product/Save.php(110): Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Interceptor->save()
#30 /home/tesefa/public_html/generated/code/Magento/Catalog/Controller/Adminhtml/Product/Save/Interceptor.php(24): Magento\Catalog\Controller\Adminhtml\Product\Save->execute()
#31 /home/tesefa/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/App/Action/Action.php(107): Magento\Catalog\Controller\Adminhtml\Product\Save\Interceptor->execute()
#32 /home/tesefa/public_html/vendor/magento/module-backend/App/AbstractAction.php(229): Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#33 /home/tesefa/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(58): Magento\Backend\App\AbstractAction->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#34 /home/tesefa/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138): Magento\Catalog\Controller\Adminhtml\Product\Save\Interceptor->___callParent('dispatch', Array)
#35 /home/tesefa/public_html/vendor/magento/module-backend/App/Action/Plugin/Authentication.php(143): Magento\Catalog\Controller\Adminhtml\Product\Save\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#36 /home/tesefa/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(135): Magento\Backend\App\Action\Plugin\Authentication->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\Catalog\Controller\Adminhtml\Product\Save\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#37 /home/tesefa/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(153): Magento\Catalog\Controller\Adminhtml\Product\Save\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#38 /home/tesefa/public_html/generated/code/Magento/Catalog/Controller/Adminhtml/Product/Save/Interceptor.php(39): Magento\Catalog\Controller\Adminhtml\Product\Save\Interceptor->___callPlugins('dispatch', Array, NULL)
#39 /home/tesefa/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/App/FrontController.php(55): Magento\Catalog\Controller\Adminhtml\Product\Save\Interceptor->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#40 /home/tesefa/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(58): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#41 /home/tesefa/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->___callParent('dispatch', Array)
#42 /home/tesefa/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(153): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#43 /home/tesefa/public_html/generated/code/Magento/Framework/App/FrontController/Interceptor.php(26): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->___callPlugins('dispatch', Array, Array)
#44 /home/tesefa/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/App/Http.php(135): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#45 /home/tesefa/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/App/Bootstrap.php(256): Magento\Framework\App\Http->launch()
#46 /home/tesefa/public_html/index.php(39): Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Http))
#47 {main} [] []
```

Comment: please check var/system.log and exception.log 
so we may get exact problem.

Comment: Are you using Nginx. If you are then please use the Nginx conf for that came with Magento

Comment: No. I am using - Apache Version - 2.4.29, PHP Version - 5.6.33, MySQL Version - 5.6.38

Comment: I have uploaded the VAR/SYSTEM.LOG also. Can you guys help me!

Comment: Magento 2.2 in php 5.6? check here http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/install-gde/system-requirements-tech.html

Comment: Yes. I have checked this URL and followed it up with every rule.

Comment: @Venkatesha any solutions please?

Comment: Are you add any source inventory from store > Inventory > source ?. Please check once.

Answer (score 0):

Please run re-index command in your Magento root directory:

> php bin/magento indexer:reindex

After flush the cache(`php bin/magento cache:flush`) and then try saving the product again.

Answer (score 0):

Set your indices on "**UPDATE ON SCHEDULE**" instead of "**UPDATE ON SAVE**".

Now you will be able to save products. For indices update run:

```
php bin/magento indexer:reindex
```

Hope it helps ;)